# get belonging notebook to note from an .enex-file

Tags: evernote

I have notes exported to enex. I want to process them with php-cli (the language I am most mature). There is no way to get the name of the notebook, a note is belonging to, is it? Are there plans to include this information into the .enex-files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you won't be able to get the notebook from the enex file.

There's nothing in [the DTD](http://xml.evernote.com/pub/evernote-export3.dtd) and as stated in [this blog post](https://blog.evernote.com/tech/2013/08/08/evernote-export-format-enex/) :

> ENEX files do not represent how notes are stored within the Evernote service or applications; they are a portable export format that allows notes to be migrated in their entirety between systems and accounts.

And I'm pretty confident that this won't change anytime soon, sorry.